# New pc issue - no display signal and 1 long 2 short beeps

Tags: display, motherboard, gpu, beep-code

At first, my hardware:

```
Motherboard: MSI B550M PRO-VDH WIFI
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3100
GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 1050Ti Low Profile
RAM: 2 x 8 GB HYPERX HX432C16PB3A/8
PSU: Chieftec CSN-650C 650W
SSD: ADATA SWORDFISH m.2 2280PCIe Gen3x4
Body: Aerocool Playa Slim
```

So, the problem is no video signal after launch (tried 3 displays and 3 cables), only 1 long beep and 2 short beeps and thats all. Removing GPU don't fixing the problem, try reassemble it many times with ram too, trying various ram combinations, nothing happens. PC have around 1 month, yesterday everything works fine. Somebody can help me fix that?

Comment: One long and two short is a video card problem.

Comment: What if you remove RAM completely and power on? Do you hear the same beeps  1 long + 2 short? Repeat that removing external components one at a time like RAM, GPU etc.

Comment: @patkim remove all ram gives 3 long beep, I try today to test GPU, I think that was a issue with motherboard, but all components have warranty.

Comment: @patkim GPU tested, working on different PC

Comment: This may not be of much help but just try clearing CMOS and see if that makes any difference. However after this step if by default system speaker is set to OFF in BIOS, beeps will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't believe it, the issue is ... HDMI cable. I tried 3 cables and all of them are broken. After using new one from new display, problem just solved.